# Getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when trying to play video in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to play a video file in JavaFX, but getting errors

My Code (trying the code from a website)

```
package application;  
 
import javafx.application.Application;  
import javafx.scene.Group;  
import javafx.scene.Scene;  
import javafx.scene.media.Media;  
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;  
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;  
import javafx.stage.Stage; 

public class Main extends Application  
{  
  
    @Override  
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {  
        
        String path = "src\\Funny.mp4";  
          
       
        Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());  
          
        
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);  
          
       
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);  
          
       
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);  
          
       
        Group root = new Group();  
        root.getChildren().add(mediaView);  
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,400);  
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);  
        primaryStage.setTitle("Playing video");  
        primaryStage.show();  
    }  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        launch(args);  
    }  
      
}
```

And my errors are :

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/media/Media
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:21)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.media.Media
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 10 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

I have tried the following so far :

1. My regular JavaFX runs fine
2. Since the error shows "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/media/Media" - I downloaded Jar files for javafx/scene/media/Media and set it up in both ClassPath as well as in JavaFX Library
3. Check file corrections by creating a File instance, works fine.
4. Tried other codes in previous stackoverflow questions but error remains same.
5. Broke the code and executed one by one, start getting the errors from Media media = new Media.......

Appreciate any inputs

Comment: verify the the media module is on the runtime path

Comment: Could you please elaborate that..I'm on eclipse

Comment: You are doing something (e.g. runtime settings or entries in `module-info.java`, depending on how you set up the project) to add the `javafx.graphics` and/or `javafx.controls` modules. You *also* need to add the `javafx.media` module in the same way.

Comment: @James_D that's what I said, or didn't I :) Thanks for spelling it out in an understandable way.

Comment: @kleopatra It is indeed what you said. I have no idea why the OP needed to hear it twice.

Comment: My bad...blame it on lack of knowledge..thanks kleopatra & James_D again